# Navigate to pages through selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to navigate from page to page using selenium VBA. This is what I got when inspecting the html page

```html
<div class="paging bottom" style="cursor: pointer;"><a data-page="1" href="#" class="prev"><div id="triangle-left"></div> Prev</a><span>1</span><a data-page="2">2</a><a data-page="3">3</a><a data-page="4">4</a>..<a data-page="5">5</a><a data-page="2" href="#" class="next">Next <div id="triangle-right"></div></a></div>
```

I am confused how to refer to each page. When inspecting the # symbol in the href attribute I found the same link for all the pages
https://www.file-up.org/?op=my_files#
No indications of how to change from page to page. And how can I determine the total of pages that is in this pagination part?

I could solve that partially like that

```
        For i = 1 To 5
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        p = p + 1

        Set fStream = New ADODB.Stream
        With fStream
            .Charset = "UTF-8"
            .Open
            .WriteText bot.PageSource
            .SaveToFile Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & p & ".mhtml", 2
            .Close
        End With

        On Error Resume Next
        Set btn = .FindElementByCss("a.next")
        If btn.IsPresent = True Then
            btn.Click
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
```

But there are two notes. First I have to type the total pages in the loop line
Another point, how can I make the code wait till the page is loaded and the html page source is saved? that point confused me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following xpath to get the number of pages.

```
//a[@data-page][last()-1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried `For i = 1 To .FindElementByXPath("//a[@data-page][last()-1]")` but not work. I have tried using `.Count` and also `.Length` but with no way. It worked with `.Text'. Thanks a lot for solving the first point. Now how can I wait till the page is loaded and saved properly.

Comment: `For i = 1 To .FindElementByXPath("//a[@data-page][last()-1]")` I don't see your driver reference before `.FindElementByXpath`. And did you tried that xpath in the chrome dev tools as shown in my screenshot to check if it's working in your case? Btw, what's the error that you received when you tried the code from the above comment?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The point of detecting the number of pages is perfect now. Can you please guide me with the second point?

Comment: Your current logic should be fine for clicking on the next button. But you have to find a common element on the page and then wait for the element to displayed using explicit wait.

Comment: I can't see any common element. I didn't get what you mean exactly?

Comment: You can try waituntil `//a[@data-page][last()]` value  equals to `p+1`

Comment: I tried and used F8 to follow the value of it and found `.FindElementByXPath("//a[@data-page][last()]").Text)` is always 0.